# Is Indexeddb OpenCursor on Chromium being throttled on non-active tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, indexeddb, throttling

I've been reading lately that Chrome will throttle background tab processes  from Chrome 57 onwards ([here](http://www.bgr.in/news/google-chrome-v57-update-focuses-on-reducing-cpu-load-better-battery-life/)). I'm running Chromium 55 and noticed that my indexeddb queries were running at a much slower pace when a tab was not in focus.

For example, I have:

```
return openIndexedDB(this)
  .push(function (db) {
    return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var tx = openTransaction(db, ["metadata"], "readonly");
      if (options.include_docs === true) {
        handleCursor(tx.objectStore("metadata").index("_id").openCursor(),
          pushIncludedMetadata, resolve, reject);
      } else {
        handleCursor(tx.objectStore("metadata").index("_id")
                        .openKeyCursor(), pushMetadata, resolve, reject);
      }
    });
  })
  .push(function () {
    return result_list;
  });
};
```

with `handleCursor` being:

```
  function handleCursor(request, callback, resolve, reject) {
    request.onerror = function (error) {
      if (request.transaction) {
        request.transaction.abort();
      }
      reject(error);
    };

    request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
      var cursor = evt.target.result;
      if (cursor) {
        // XXX Wait for result
        console.log("waiting");
        try {
          console.log("done");
          callback(cursor);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }

        // continue to next iteration
        cursor["continue"]();
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    };
  }
```

My indexeddb database has only about 60 records (JSON, each <1k). Looping over them in the active browser tab is almost instant, while on a non-active tab, this suddenly takes upwards of two minutes to finish.

**Question**:  Is this related to browser vendor efforts of slowing down background tab processes? If so, are flags to disable/sources to read up on?

Comment: If it is then you must be taking more than 1% CPU, that seems high for a 60 records of JSON.  Looking at your code above `// XXX Wait for result`, you have missed this part out, what does your code do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome 55 there was an issue with how background tab throttling and Indexed DB interacted: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675372 - short version: event delivery was limited to once per second, so cursors (for example) would iterate very slowly.

In 56 and later, once a transaction has started in a background tab the Indexed DB events should not be throttled.

Comment: ah. thank you very much for the link. the one I was looking for and what I've been experiencing. It did force me to reduce queries on background tabs, so positive side effect overall...